# Have PhpStorm recognise my parameter as a class

Tags: php, phpstorm, intellisense

I'd like to know if there's a way to tell PhpStorm my parameter is a class. Reason being, when I start to work on the class passed in I'm constantly switching between files to view method names and etc.

Any possible way to get code completion to show method names from the parameter?

EDIT:

```
public function create($form) {
        //have PhpStorm generate the method names for the class "form" passed in as a paramter 
        $driverId   = (int) $form->getLastDriverId();
    }
```

Instead you have to do it manually switching back an fourth between files to get the method names.

Comment: can you provide examples of the code in question so we can know exactly what you mean?

Comment: Just did, hope that helps if not let me know

Comment: Why standard `public function create (FormClass $form)` is not good for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try this out:

```
/**
 * @param Form $form  // where "Form" is your class name
 */
public function create($form) {
    $driverId   = (int) $form->getLastDriverId();
}
```

Comment: Thanks a mil, Do I have to use @var though? Or can I use the default @params?

Comment: no problem. I believe the docs say to use `@var` but if `@params` works then go with that because it makes more sense.

Comment: @DBoyDaniel You have to use `@param` to declare function parameters. `@var` is for class properties/inline variables. If you going to use `@var` as suggested in this answer then one day, after you modify your code, it may break and stop working.